24-hour time format interpreted incorrectly in "Schedule send"
When using "Schedule send" in Gmail, I prefer to specify the time in 24-hour format to avoid ambiguity so I don't enter the time incorrectly, especially around the hours of midnight and noon.
I noticed that when entering time in 24-hour format and then unfocusing the input box, Gmail would automatically convert the time to 12-hour format. However, the choice of AM/PM seems arbitrary.
For example, 06:00 would be converted to 6:00 AM but 03:00 would be incorrectly converted to 3:00 PM!

How can I ensure that Gmail sets the correct time?

You are correct
As you noted, the 'Schedule send' interface does not correctly interpret 24-hour time when the 'display language' is set to a locale that uses 12-hour formatted time.
It may be a bug since conversely, when the 'display language' is set to a locale that uses 24-hour formatted time, times entered in 12-hour format are properly interpreted and converted.
Options
Enter time in 12-hour format

Keep everything the same, but in the 'Schedule send'  interface enter times 12-hour formatted instead of 24-hour.
To avoid making errors related to noon and midnight, you might offset those times by a minute or two  which will make identifying the correct period, AM or PM, much easier.
For example:

11:59 AM for noon instead of 12 PM
11:59 PM for midnight instead of 12 AM



Switch Gmail to 24-hour time

Making this change will allow the 'Schedule send' interface to properly interpret 24-hour formatted times as well as 12-hour formatted times.
Note that this change will affect the way times are displayed throughout Gmail, including in messages.
Instructions:

In Gmail, navigate to Settings > General
( mail.google.com/mail#settings/general )
In the Language section at the top of the page, change the 'Gmail display language' to 'English (UK)'
 
Important: Changes to this setting are not automatically saved on your behalf. You must click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the page.




